# Unity3d Multiplayer Unet - multiple host in dedicated server

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

Before I come to this forum ... I was ask this question in unity's `answers.unity3d` and forum  but after 2 month ... there is no one answer and help or guide me a little bit...  anyway ....

My question is :

I am working on a simple multiplayer game...
And I want to use only dedicated server for this game. But in lobby, I don't know how can I have multiple hosts to join.

I mean when I run server... it does not matter I run 1 server or 10 server.
When I want to join as a client (in u-net Lobby) always show 1 server.
And my problem is here.

What i want is in my game u-net lobby, have a list of hosts and players choose one of them and then join to that room.

For example when i run 4 exe as server ... then in lobby show 4 host and clients choose one of them.

So, is anybody here to guide me how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a master server. It will register hosts and clients, and makes clients joins by the way you want

- Put clients in a queue when then want to play, and redirect them to an available host.
- Send them a list of available hosts when they click a "Browser servers" button...

This can be done in a lot of different ways, but you'll have to make your own or to use a third-party lib because UNET master server is far from being ready.

I'm having good results with a dedicated unity build using a custom NetworkServer class.